# How to Create a Program that Prints Identical String?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code that reads string from file1.txt and file2.txt, compare them both, and if there are identical words that are contained in both files, it will print them to the screen and to filemerge.txt. The problem is, it works for the first two lines (because both of the lines are identical) and the program ends without reading the next line (I think). Also, the string that is printed into filemerge.txt is a bunch of random characters.

I'm a newbie at programming, so if my code/syntax is confusing, or I made silly mistakes, I'm really sorry.

file1.txt contains:

```
Milimeter
Centimeter
Kilometer
Megameter
Gigameter
Terrameter
```

and file2.txt contains:

```
Milimeter
Centimeter
Decimeter
Decameter
Megameter
Gigameter
Yotameter
```

So far, I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000

void compareFiles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
    char ch1[MAXCHAR];
    char ch2[MAXCHAR];
    int compare_string;
    FILE *fpmerge;

    fpmerge = fopen("filemerge.txt", "w");

    checkpoint_true:
    while (fgets(ch1, MAXCHAR, fp1) != NULL){
        checkpoint_false:
        while (fgets(ch2, MAXCHAR, fp2) != NULL){
            compare_string = strcmp(ch1, ch2);
            if (compare_string == 0){
                puts(ch1);
                goto checkpoint_true;
            }
            else{
                goto checkpoint_false;
            }
        }
    }
    fwrite(&ch1, sizeof(ch1), 1, fpmerge);
    fclose(fpmerge);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("file2.txt", "r");

    if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(0);
    }

    compareFiles(fp1, fp2);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
Milimeter

Centimeter
```

And the string written in filemerge.txt is just some random characters:

```
Terrameter  ü         P6q     `6q
```

Thank you for reading this, and I'm really hoping to get an answer since I can't find what I needed.

Comment: When you start seeing junk data, look for improperly terminated C strings.

Comment: Please, for the sake of everyone, including yourself, **get rid of these `goto` statements**. These lead to code that is hard to follow, harder to maintain, and full of surprising bugs that shouldn't exist in the first place. There are exceedingly rare cases where `goto` is justified, but this isn't even close to that threshold. What you're looking for here is `break`.

Comment: The program reads "Kilometer" from file1.txt, and then reads to the end of file2.txt, because file2.txt doesn't contain "Kilometer". Then the program reads the rest of the lines from file1.txt, but there's nothing to compare against, because file2.txt is already finished.

Comment: The `fwrite` doesn't do anything useful. You should delete that line. Inside the loops, replace `puts(ch1)` with `fputs(ch1, fpmerge)` to write matching lines to the output file.

Comment: Got it. Replace goto with break, and fwrite with fputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Huge thanks to @tadman and @user3386109 for the answers.
I edited the code so the looping part looks like this:

```
    while (fgets(ch1, MAXCHAR, fp1) != NULL){
        while (fgets(ch2, MAXCHAR, fp2) != NULL){
            compare_string = strcmp(ch1, ch2);
            if (compare_string == 0){
                fputs(ch1, fpmerge);
                puts(ch1);
                break;
            }
        }
        rewind(fp2);
    }
    fclose(fpmerge);
```

Currently, it works well. The program now prints this out to the output and writes it into the file "fpmerge.txt":

```
Milimeter

Centimeter
 
Megameter
 
Gigameter
```

I'm worried about the rewind function though. Is its usage already correct? Or is it bad practice to use it?

Comment: Using `rewind` is ok for small files. For large files, you should expect the code to take a very long time, because it will potentially read all of file2.txt for each line in file1.txt. Another potential problem is duplicate lines in file1.txt. For example, if "Kilometer" appears twice in file1.txt, but only once in file2.txt, the code will output "Kilometer" twice, even though it only appears once in file2.txt. A solution to both problems is to read all of file2.txt into memory. Then for each line in file1.txt, you can look for a match in memory, and mark that line as used.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you dump out the *whole* raw buffer, not just the part with data:

```c
fwrite(&ch1, strlen(ch1), 1, fpmerge);
```

Use `strlen` to determine how long a given string is. `sizeof()` is almost never the correct tool.